# Weird output from custom string class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a custom string class in C++. However, when I try to output the value of the string, I get the value + a bunch of junk.

Class:

```cpp
unsigned str_len;
char* str_val; // Both set as private in the header file

str::string::string(const char* value) {
    if (value) {
        unsigned n = 0;
        while (value[n] != '\0')
            n++;

        str_val = new char[n];
        str_len = n;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++)
            str_val[i] = value[i]; 
    }
    else {
        str_val = new char[0];
        str_len = 0;
    }
}

unsigned str::string::len() { return str_len; }

char* str::string::val() {
    char* value = new char[str_len];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < str_len; i++)
        value[i] = str_val[i];

    return value;
}
```

Main file:

```cpp
int main() {
    str::string test("test");
    std::cout << "String length: " << test.len() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "String value: " << test.val() << std::endl;
}
```

Expected output:

```
String length: 4
String value: test
```

Actual output:

```
String length: 4
String value: test²²²²¼s╜ù÷f
```

Comment: C strings are null-terminated.

Comment: You know why do you iterate up to `\0` when calulating string length? Because `\0` marks the end of a string. What happens if your string doesn't have an end mark (a.k.a. null terminator)? The compiler will not know when to stop reading it.

Comment: I don't believe you null terminate your strings in your code. Also, remember to free your memory, probably through copy-control in your class. You may find it easier to return a `const char*` to the internally stored string than to create a copy that needs to be freed.

Comment: Null terminate your strings. Also; does C++ *really* need another string class? I mean, we've got `gstring`, `QString`, `std::string`, `std::wstring`, `sf::String`, and basic C strings - and many, *many* more. Do we *really* need to add another?

Comment: @JesperJuhl We sure do, if we want programmers that understand manual memory management rather than another batch of Java programmers.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I'd rather have them understand automatic memory management via `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr` *first*, rather than learning manual memory management via `new`/`delete`.

Comment: Also bear in mind that `std::cout << "String value: " << test.val() << std::endl;` allocates but not deletes the char array it returns from `test.val()`, resulting in garbage. If you really want to return a newly allocated array, a nicer way would be to return `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen -- You're going to get another batch of Java programmers anyway when they're taught C++ in this fashion.  They will drop C++ and go to Java, C# (or some other language).  And in any event, is the student really learning how to *properly* put together such a class?  I highly doubt it.  They will get an `A` or `B+`, even though the string class is shoddy, full of memory leaks, not exception safe, etc.  Better to show the student a well put-together string class *first*, and *then* learn the techniques, instead of throwing them in the fire like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the '\0' at the end of your new string. It's not copied into the str_val (you stop just short).

Since you seem to want str_len to represent the number of printable characters, I would recommend that you allocate value to be one larger, and make the last character a '\0'.

```
char* str::string::val() {
    char* value = new char[str_len + 1];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < str_len; i++)
        value[i] = str_val[i];
    value[str_len] = '\0';
    return value;
}
```